# How to add arguments to event handler in ES6 React when functions are bound in constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

With constructors in es6, we are advised to bind functions early, e.g.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); // bound early
  }

  handleClick() {
    // do stuff
  }
  ...
}
```

In ES5, we could typically call something like `this.handleClick.bind(this, "foo")` if we wanted to preserve context AND send an extra argument. What is the best pattern for this with the new class syntax in ES6 React?

For instance, if my class looked like the code below, how would I best access the `"foo"` and `"bar`" values? (I know the answer is not `bind` but this is how I could best illustrate the problem).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); // bound early
  }

  handleClick(event, value) {
    // do stuff with value ("foo" or "baz")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind("foo")} /> // incorrect code
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind("bar")} /> // incorrect code
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The first argument to `.bind` is always the `this` value. Therefore you would want `this.handleClick.bind(null, "foo")`. Since the function was already bound in the constructor, any value you pass as first argument is ignored.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Think that:

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

Is the same as:

```
onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}
```

So you can do:

```
    <button onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, 'foo')} />
    <button onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, 'baz')} />
```

In the end it is all just JavaScript.

Comment: What exactly does "incorrect code" mean in this answer?

Comment: This way will create a new function in each render, which slows down the app since React has to unregiste the old handler and register the new handler.

Answer (score 6):

> In ES5, we could typically call something like `this.handleClick.bind(this, "foo")` if we wanted to preserve context AND send an extra argument.

You can do *exactly*  the same in ES6 as well. It's not like `bind` was removed from the language :-)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleFooClick = this.handleClick.bind(this, "foo"); // bind early
  }

  handleClick(value, event) {
    //        ^^^^^^ notice the bound values come first
    …
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleFooClick} /> // use early-bound
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "bar")} /> // bind late
        <button onClick={event => this.handleClick("foobar", event)} /> // arrow function
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: @elclanrs: Oops, that messed up arguments order in the `bind` call was a typo. `this.handleClick.bind(this, "bar")` should be equivalent to `(...args) => this.handleClick("bar", ...args)`

Comment: This answer saved my bacon in a vanilla ES6/babel with classes scenario, thanks.

Comment: Note that this will crate a new function each time the component is rendered, slowing down the app a bit.

Comment: @JF Then use the early-bound alternative I've shown